# Why wont the draw() command draw my circle

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a ball every time someone touches the screen, but i can't seem to get it to work. I want it to be created in a certain location and spawn a ball. There is an if statement which sees if there is a tap on the screen, and in the if statement it calls the draw that is made below to draw a circle in the window.

```
package com.example.madusha.gravityball;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameWindow extends Activity {
private Paint paint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_window);

    Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pausebutton);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(GameWindow.this, PauseMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    int Action = event.getAction();
    if(Action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        onDraw();
        System.out.println("Works???");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
}
public void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}
Canvas canvas;
public void onDraw(){
    init();
    int height = 100;
    int width = 100;
    canvas.drawCircle(width, height,100,paint);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it might be because you haven't returned true inside the if statement after Draw().

Comment: I did that, but it didn't seem to do anything that i can see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the OnDraw() function. That is what updates the canvas when drawing stuff.

Comment: How do i do that, i am new to android development and don't know how to do that or what you mean at all.

Comment: there is a OnDraw method, Implement it, i.e write your code inside it. This OnDraw method draws everything on your canvas. if you put your code in any other function, the OS will not know what to draw, so they have given the OnDraw method

Comment: I did what i think you told me to do and it still doesn't work, i have replaced my old code with the one above.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing to a canvas can only be done inside a `View` object, not an activity like the one that you have in the example. You could create your own custom view something like this -

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private Paint paint;

public CompletionSliderView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, height/2, paint);
}

}
```

To use this in an xml layout, you will need to do this, replacing the package name (probably `com.yourcompany.yourapp`).

```
<com.yourcompany.yourapp.CustomView
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"/>
```

You can create a new view in code by doing

```
View circle = new CustomView(getContext());
```

Then you can add this to your layout.

Comment: but if i do this, will it still spawn the ball in the activity that i have used